# map or set with transparent comparator and non-unique elements in heterogeneous sense

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++14, heterogeneous

Given `std::set< T, less >` or `std::map< T, less >` container of unique elements. `less` is heterogeneous comparator. I.e. it can compare value of some another type `U` against a value of type `T`. Whereas all the values of type `T` are unique, there are (maybe) a plenty of values of type `T`, that compare equal to some particular value of type `U`. Is it undefined behaviour?

Say, I want to find (one) element in the container, which have the key, equivalent to the value of type `U`. Any one: either first, last or middle of them if there more then one. I know, that there are more then one element in the container, which are equivalent to the value `u` of type `U`. Can I use `std::set::find` or `std::map::find` function for? Is it *undefined behaviour*?

Example (here imprecise comparison with tolerance `0.2`):

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

double const eps = 0.2;

struct less
{
    bool operator () (double l, double r) const { return l < r; }
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator () (int l, double r) const { return l + eps < r; }
    bool operator () (double l, int r) const { return l + eps < r; }
};

int main()
{
    std::set< double, less > s{0.0, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0};
    for (auto it = s.find(1); it != std::end(s); it = s.find(1)) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
        s.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Output (order generally unspecified):

> 0.9 1 1.1

Is it UB to use associative ordered containers of unique elements as above?

Should I use `std::multiset` and `std::multimap` instead?

Comment: I think you meant "plenty of values of type **`U`** that compare equal to a given `T`"

Comment: Your example `less` does not define a strict weak ordering when comparing int and double.  That looks very likely to be a cause for grief.  OTOH, a comparison like `operator ()(std::pair<double, char> lhs, double rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs; }` looks much less likely to be troublesome.

Comment: @MartinBonner No. Exactly as described. Above example illustrate this possibility.

Comment: The question is fundamental - can I start a bounty right now? I want to grant a huge amount of reputation for the good answer.

Comment: There is no requirement for `U` and `T` to be striclty ordered. They can be equal. It is permitted. Say, `1.1` of type `double` and `1` of type `int` are equal if one use `less` to compare. If `0.5 < eps` then transitivity broken, but it is not the case (`eps == 0.2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanatory text before the associative container requirements table says:

> `kl` is a value such that `a` [*sic*] is partitioned ([alg.sorting])
>   with respect to `c(r, kl)`, with `r` the key value of `e` and `e` in
>   `a`; `ku` is a value such that `a` is partitioned with respect to
>   `!c(ku, r)`; `ke` is a value such that `a` is partitioned with respect
>   to `c(r, ke)` and `!c(ke, r)`, with `c(r, ke)` implying `!c(ke, r)`.

And then describes the behavior of `a_tran.{find,count,equal_range}(ke)`, `a_tran.lower_bound(kl)` and `a_tran.upper_bound(ku)`. Therefore, the requirements are:

- For `find`, `count`, and `equal_range`:

  - The elements in the container must be partitioned with respect to `c(r, ke)` and `!c(ke, r)`
  - `c(r, ke)` must imply `!c(ke, r)`
- For `lower_bound`, the elements in the container must be partitioned with respect to `c(r, kl)`.
- For `upper_bound`, the elements in the container must be partitioned with respect to `!c(ku, r)`.

Provided that you meet those requirements, there's nothing wrong with using heterogeneous lookup with something that's equivalent to multiple keys in the container. The motivating example in [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf), after all, is about looking up everyone whose family name is "Smith" in a `set` of names.